# Generate cURL output from Alamofire request?

Tags: curl, alamofire

The documentation for Alamofire says that it produces cURL debug output. But for the life of me, I can't figure out how to retrieve the cURL for my request. Can someone enlighten me on the proper syntax for showing the cURL request as in my debug console?

Assuming I have a simple request of the form

```
Alamofire.request(.POST, servicePath, parameters: requestParams, encoding: .JSON)
```

Where can I inject a `print()` to see the generated request?

Answer (score 34, accepted):

I just did this and it works:

```
let someRequest = Alamofire.request(.POST, servicePath, parameters: requestParams, encoding: .JSON)
debugPrint(someRequest)
```

Comment: Thanks, I don't know why I didn't try this to begin with. It never occurred to me that Alamofire.request() actually returned an object.

Comment: Hi, I use this one but I can't get a valid response when I tried to paste it on terminal. Guys di you experience this one?

Comment: It just saying 'No request created yet.'

Answer (score 11):

Here's an updated answer for Swift 5 and AlamoFire 5

```
let headers: HTTPHeaders = [
    "Accept": "application/json"
]

AF.request(myURL, method: .get, headers: headers).validate().responseJSON { response in
    switch response.result {
        case .success(let value):
            print(value)
        case .failure(let error):
            print("oops")
            print(error)
        }
}.cURLDescription { description in
    print(description)
}
```

Comment: But the curl does not seems to work on Postman :(
Format not recognized error. Any solution for that?

Comment: @AnkitKumarGupta you need to copy only curl part, not above the curl where it says type of req (GET/POST etc) and the url.

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
let task = AF.request(url)
task.responseData { response in
   print(task.debugDescription)
}
```

from [here](https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire/issues/2816#issuecomment-489130708)

Answer (score -3):

Try this code

```
Alamofire.request(.POST, url, parameters: parameters, encoding: .JSON, headers: headers)
                .responseJSON { response in
                    print(response.request)
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but that just prints the raw NSMutableURLRequest which is not in the form of a cURL command.